# A,B,C are angles of an acute angled triangle , what is the minimum value of $\sin^4A+(1-\sin A)^4+\sin^4B+(1-\sin B)^4+\sin^4C+(1-\sin C)^4$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> If A,B,C are angles of an acute angled triangle then what is the minimum value of $\sin^4A+(1-\sin A)^4+\sin^4B+(1-\sin B)^4+\sin^4C+(1-\sin C)^4$

My attempt: 
If I see those terms as six positive numbers then it is clear that minimum value would occur when all of them are $1\over 16$ , but in that case the $A+B+C=π$ is not followed . I can't seem to find a way to minimize it with the restriction that these are angles of an acute angled triangle . So I am stuck here , could someone please give me some hint on how to proceed ?

Thanks !

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimise+%28sin+a%29%5E4+%2B+%281+-+sin+a%29%5E4+%2B+%28sin+b%29%5E4+%2B+%281+-+sin+b%29%5E4+%2B+%28sin+c%29%5E4+%2B+%281+-+sin+c%29%5E4+when+a%2Bb%2Bc%3Dpi%2C+0%3Ca%3Cpi%2F2%2C+0%3Cb%3Cpi%2F2%2C+0%3Cc%3Cpi%2F2) suggests that the minimum is attained when $a = \frac{\pi}{4}, b = \frac{\pi}{2}, c = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

let $f(x)=\sin^4x+(1-\sin{x})^4.$

Thus, $f''(x)>0$ for any $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq x<\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Also, at least two angles are greater or equal to $\frac{\pi}{4},$ otherwise we'll get a contradiction with the fact that our triangle is an acute angled triangle.

Id est, after using Jensen it's enough to find a minimal value for equality case of two variables.

Can you end it now?

I got $10-6\sqrt2.$